# Find a Function That Satisfies the Following Criteria

Tags: limits

Find a function $f$ satisfying both

1. $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$;
2. $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ does not exist.

This one got me stumped
(Sorry in advance for the bad formatting, I cant seem to get it)

Comment: "does not exist" = "undefined" or "infinite" ?

Comment: doesn't specify, just states "does not exist" I would assume it's undefined.

Comment: well, in the acception of undefined then the example by @quasi is a good example

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=|x|$.

Can you verify that this works?

Comment: yes I believe this works, thank you.